# Transforming a list containting integers into string

Tags: python, string, list

I want to transform list to a string, but it contains integers. It works now, anyway that's the code:

```
for player in basicPlayers:
  say('Name' + str(player['name']) + 'score' + str(player['score']))
```

Sooo yeah, I want to make it like

```
Player1 (2), Player2 (4), Player3 (6)
```

not

```
Player1 (2) 
Player2 (4)
Player3 (6)
```

The code that gets the data:

```
def getBasicPlayers(self): # Finished
        """Returns a list containing a dictionary for each player:
        [
            {
                'name' : string,
                'score' : integer,
            },
            {
                'name' : string,
                'score' : integer,
            },
        ]
        Note: This will return an empty list if the player count is above 100."""
        packet = self.assemblePacket("c")
        self.send(packet)

        reply = self.receive()
        reply = reply[11:] # Clean up bytes
        players = []

        strLen = struct.unpack("<h", reply[0:2])
        playerCount = strLen[0]

        reply = reply[2:] # Clean up bytes

        for i in range(playerCount):
            players.append({'name' : '', 'score' : 0})

        pointer = 0

        for player in players:
            strLen = ord(reply[pointer:(pointer + 1)])

            name = reply[(pointer + 1):(pointer + (strLen + 1))]

            temp = struct.unpack("<i", reply[(pointer + (strLen + 1)):(pointer + (strLen + 5))])
            pointer += (strLen + 5)

            player['name'] = name
            player['score'] = temp[0]

        return players
```

Comment: What's the problem again? Your example `Player1 (2), Player2 (4)...` doesn't match your printing.

Comment: There's no problem, I just don't know how to transform it into string, so it won't be a list. I tried with .join but it contains integers and I read somewhere that it's impossible with .join if it contains integers (also by 'it works' I meant that the code works, there's no problem with it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
', '.join('Name %(name)s Score %(score)d' % player for player in basicPlayers)
```

Note that `join` takes any *iterable* as its argument, in this case we pass a generator expression to it.

---

For example:

```
basicPlayers = [{'name' : 'Bob','score' : 42}, {'name' : 'Joe','score' : 24}]

print ', '.join('Name %(name)s Score %(score)d' % 
                                           player for player in basicPlayers)
```

```
Name Bob Score 42, Name Joe Score 24
```

Comment: It might be worth explaining that this utilises a [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use the `format` function, I think.

```
>>> basicPlayers = [{'name': 'John', 'score': 1}, {'name': 'Mary', 'score': 2}]
>>> ', '.join(('{name} ({score})'.format(**player) for player in basicPlayers))
'John (1), Mary (2)'
```